# Problem with dhcp in Debian

Tags: debian, ip-address, dhcp, static-ip

I try to have a static ip adress on an host.

I execute the following commands :

```
$ ip address eth0 10.4.1.15 netmask 255.255.255.0

$ route add default gw 10.4.1.5
```

But later my IP address changes on `10.4.1.241` unless I have commented the request command in `dhcplient.conf` and I have put into `/etc/network/interfaces` the following:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.4.1.14
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.4.1.5
```

Please help me I don't understand why my ip changes ?

Thanks in advance.

Narglix

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/network/interfaces` holds your default configuration... so if you need a permanent static IP, put it in there like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address <THE IP YOU WANT>
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway <THE IP OF YOUR GATEWAY (Usually your router)>
```

The commands you executed only adjusts your configuration temporarily.

Comment: You also need to remove the line for dhcp, or at least you should.


iface eth0 inet dhcp # <== Remove this

Comment: I don't see the difference than I have made

Comment: @user32433 - Your IP shouldn't change when that is in your interfaces file.